# How do I use SOAP::Lite with WCF?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, perl, soaplite

I'm just trying to get started with WCF.  It sounds like it is supposed to be super simple, but using a simple API like SOAP::Lite, I am having trouble getting anything to work.  There are a lot of out dated examples in the googlesphere, and I have tried many of them to no avail.  So now I am trying to break down the problem to its lowest level.  I created the WCF app generated by the Visual Web Developer 2008 Express template.  This is its service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}


// Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    bool boolValue = true;
    string stringValue = "Hello ";

    [DataMember]
    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return boolValue; }
        set { boolValue = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringValue; }
        set { stringValue = value; }
    }
}
```

I started it up in debug mode and tried to make contact.  Doing so with a browser using the debug url `http://localhost:59315/Service1.svc` gives me a page saying this:

> You have created a service.
>
> To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to
>   call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the
>   command line with the following syntax:
>
> svcutil.exe `http://localhost:59315/Service1.svc?wsdl`

So, then I brows to that wsdl and get this:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="Service1" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
  <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService1_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <sp:SymmetricBinding>
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:ProtectionToken>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:SecureConversationToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                  <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:RequireDerivedKeys/>
                    <sp:BootstrapPolicy>
                      <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:SignedParts>
                          <sp:Body/>
                          <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                          <sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                          <sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                          <sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                          <sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                          <sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                          <sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                        </sp:SignedParts>
                        <sp:EncryptedParts>
                          <sp:Body/>
                        </sp:EncryptedParts>
                        <sp:SymmetricBinding>
                          <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:ProtectionToken>
                              <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:SpnegoContextToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                  <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:RequireDerivedKeys/>
                                  </wsp:Policy>
                                </sp:SpnegoContextToken>
                              </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:ProtectionToken>
                            <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                              <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Basic256/>
                              </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                            <sp:Layout>
                              <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Strict/>
                              </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:Layout>
                            <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                            <sp:EncryptSignature/>
                            <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
                          </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:SymmetricBinding>
                        <sp:Wss11>
                          <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>
                            <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
                            <sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint/>
                            <sp:MustSupportRefEncryptedKey/>
                          </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:Wss11>
                        <sp:Trust10>
                          <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens/>
                            <sp:RequireClientEntropy/>
                            <sp:RequireServerEntropy/>
                          </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:Trust10>
                      </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:BootstrapPolicy>
                  </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:SecureConversationToken>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:ProtectionToken>
            <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:Basic256/>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
            <sp:Layout>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:Strict/>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Layout>
            <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
            <sp:EncryptSignature/>
            <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:SymmetricBinding>
        <sp:Wss11>
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>
            <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
            <sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint/>
            <sp:MustSupportRefEncryptedKey/>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:Wss11>
        <sp:Trust10>
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens/>
            <sp:RequireClientEntropy/>
            <sp:RequireServerEntropy/>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:Trust10>
        <wsaw:UsingAddressing/>
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService1_GetData_Input_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <sp:SignedParts>
          <sp:Body/>
          <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
        </sp:SignedParts>
        <sp:EncryptedParts>
          <sp:Body/>
        </sp:EncryptedParts>
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService1_GetData_output_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <sp:SignedParts>
          <sp:Body/>
          <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
        </sp:SignedParts>
        <sp:EncryptedParts>
          <sp:Body/>
        </sp:EncryptedParts>
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_Input_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <sp:SignedParts>
          <sp:Body/>
          <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
        </sp:SignedParts>
        <sp:EncryptedParts>
          <sp:Body/>
        </sp:EncryptedParts>
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_output_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <sp:SignedParts>
          <sp:Body/>
          <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
          <sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
        </sp:SignedParts>
        <sp:EncryptedParts>
          <sp:Body/>
        </sp:EncryptedParts>
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:59315/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:59315/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:59315/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RossDominosService"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="IService1_GetData_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetData"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IService1_GetData_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDataResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDataUsingDataContract"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDataUsingDataContractResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="IService1">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetData">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData" message="tns:IService1_GetData_InputMessage"/>
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataResponse" message="tns:IService1_GetData_OutputMessage"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetDataUsingDataContract">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContract" message="tns:IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_InputMessage"/>
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContractResponse" message="tns:IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_OutputMessage"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" type="tns:IService1">
    <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSHttpBinding_IService1_policy"/>
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetData">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSHttpBinding_IService1_GetData_Input_policy"/>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSHttpBinding_IService1_GetData_output_policy"/>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetDataUsingDataContract">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContract" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSHttpBinding_IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_Input_policy"/>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSHttpBinding_IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_output_policy"/>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="Service1">
    <wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" binding="tns:WSHttpBinding_IService1">
      <soap12:address location="http://localhost:59315/Service1.svc"/>
      <wsa10:EndpointReference>
        <wsa10:Address>http://localhost:59315/Service1.svc</wsa10:Address>
        <Identity>
          <Dns>localhost</Dns>
        </Identity>
      </wsa10:EndpointReference>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Nothing too crazy (other than SOAP itself)...  Anyway, now I try a simple SOAP::Lite app:

```
#!/cygdrive/C/Perl64/bin/perl.exe -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use SOAP::Lite +trace => [ transport => sub {
    my ($in) = @_;
    if ( ref($in) eq "HTTP::Request") {
        print( "REQUEST\n" . $in->content() . "\nEND REQUEST\n" );
    } 
    elsif ( ref($in) eq "HTTP::Response") {
        print( "RESPONSE\n" . $in->content() . "\nEND RESPONSE\n" );
    }
} ];


my $server = 'http://localhost:59315/Service1.svc';
my $url = "$server?wsdl";
my $xmlns = 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RossDominosService';

# Setup Network Connection
my $service = SOAP::Lite
    ->ns( $url )
    ->proxy( $server )
    ->on_fault( sub {
        my ($soap, $res) = @_;
        die ref $res ? $res->faultstring() : $soap->transport()->status(), "\n";
    } );
;

print( Dumper( $service ) );

eval {
    print( "making request\n" );
    my $response = $service->GetData( 
        SOAP::Data->new( name => 'value', value => 5 ) 
    );
    print( "got response:\n$response\n" );
};
if ( $@ ) {
    print( "failed:\n**************************\n$@\n*****************************\n" );
}
```

Which from the debug is issuing this SOAP request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:namesp1="http://localhost:59315/Service1.svc?wsdl" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <namesp1:GetData>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:int">5</value>
    </namesp1:GetData>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But the response comes back with:

```
failed:
**************************
415 Unsupported Media Type

*****************************
```

What is going on?  This is the "Hello, World!" of SOAP apps and I cant figure it out.

**-----------------------UPDATE-------------------------------**

I found that I need to change the binding from its default of `wsHttpBinding` to:

```
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              contract="RossDominosService.IService1">
```

Now it appears to connect, but I am getting this new error:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">a:ActionNotSupported</faultcode>
      <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The message with Action 'http://tempuri.org/GetData' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).</faultstring>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

It doesn't seem like this should be so hard...

**-----------------------UPDATE-------------------------------**

Got it!  After some more tinkering, and some assistance from [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/), I figured out that the action needs to be modified so that it is:

```
<namespace>/<serviceContract>/<method>
```

in this case:

```
http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData
```

When using SOAP::Lite, the default SOAPAction is

```
<namespace>#<method>
```

So you have to modify your soap object thusly:

```
$soap->on_action( sub { sprintf( '%sIService1/%s', @_ ) } );
```

I will write up the answer below so we can close this question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I accomplished getting a WCF web service up and running with a perl SOAP::Lite client.  *Note that I am using Visual Web Developer Express 2008 and perl 5.14 with SOAP::Lite 0.715.*

1. Open up Visual Web Developer
2. File -> New Project...

   1. Visual C# -> Web
   2. WCF Service Application
   3. Name: WcfService1
   4. Location:
   5. Solution: new solution
   6. Solution Name:
3. Open Web.config

   - change `<compilation debug="false">` to `<compilation debug="true">`
   - change `<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1">` to `<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1">`
4. Open Service1.svc.cs

   - press f5 (to start debugging)

Now a browser window should pop up opened to your Service page.  Take note of the port in the url, you will need it for the client.  Then create this script:

```
#!/cygdrive/C/Perl64/bin/perl.exe -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use SOAP::Lite +trace => [ transport => sub {
    my ($in) = @_;
    if ( ref($in) eq "HTTP::Request") {
        print( "**** REQUEST ****\n" . $in->content() . "\n**** END REQUEST ****\n" );
    } 
    elsif ( ref($in) eq "HTTP::Response") {
        print( "**** RESPONSE ****\n" . $in->content() . "\n**** END RESPONSE ****\n" );
    }
} ];

my $port = 63181;
my $server = "http://localhost:$port/Service1.svc";
my $namespace = 'http://tempuri.org/';

# Setup Network Connection
my $service = SOAP::Lite
    ->ns( $namespace, 'my' )
    ->proxy( $server )
    ->on_action( sub { 
        my $action = sprintf( '%sIService1/%s', @_ );
        print( "action: '$action'\n" ); 
        return $action;
    } );

print( Dumper( $service ) );

eval {
    print( "making request\n" );
    my $response = $service->GetData( 
        SOAP::Data->new( prefix => 'my', name => 'value', value => 5 ) 
    );
    print( "got response:\n$response\n" );
};
if ( $@ ) {
    print( "failed:\n**************************\n$@\n*****************************\n" );
}
```

You will need to change the port number to match your port number.  Also, I left in a bunch of the debug code so you can see what is going on.

I hope this helps someone else.